# Sources for vintage or reproduction decals?

Tags: us, paint

What sources offer reproduction decals in the vintage Cannondale (lower-case, non-italic) style? When I finish restoring my bicycle's polished aluminum finish, I would like to apply replacement decals. I've examined some products offered on eBay, but none match the really old Cannondale logo.

Comment: Check your local model shop and also any scale model railroad folks you may know.  There are services that will produce decals one-off and it's also possible to print them yourself, with the right printer and materials.

Comment: You can use a website called Identifont to identify possible fonts used by Cannondale by answering questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience with custom/stock graphics you've got three options:

1. **Manufacturer:** Contact the manufacturer, in this case Cannondale, and see if they have any sticker sheets available. Sometimes they'll have old stock, but more often they only have the last few years.
2. **3rd Party:** Look for someone selling sticker sheets or vintage logo sheets. Sometimes they may have one but not advertise it because it's not popular.
3. **Custom/Make your own:** Definitely the most time consuming option, but if you have a decent photo or reference, you can recreate the logo in your design studio of choice (Inkscape, Illustrator, etc.). Or, you can find someone to make some for you.

I recently did option 3 for a GT bike that I had powder-coated. I really wanted their new logo with the wings, but all I could find was the old GT letters. All told it was about $40US to get the decals (and extras) printed.

Comment: I already contacted Cannondale, to no avail; perhaps if the ownership and manufacturing were still here in PA... As for 3rd party, my research focused on eBay where I found a some similar decals, but not duplicates. Regarding the third option, I honestly had not considered that, but I will explore it with local sign-makers. Thank you.